# PCB Return Current Path Question

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I understand that the return current will use the closest plane to the signal trace. So could you give me answers on these 2 specific conditions.

1)When we have lets say 4 layers where layer 1 2 3 are signal layers and continuous ground plane is at 4th layer. For all 3 layers' signals the return current path will be on 4th plane right since there is no other plane.

2) Now for second case, the 4 layer stack up is signal ground-plane signal signal. Assume that layer 3 have signal traces but i also poured copper for some vcc rails **on some areas of layer 3 (not completely)**. Then if i draw a signal trace in 4th layer, will the return current be on ground plane at layer 2 or the partial copper pour on layer 3 for trace passing under partial copper pour and trace not passing under partial copper pour.

I hope i am clear.

Comment: It would be clearer if you posted some pics. Also: is a PCB intended for high-speed signals? If not, keep in mind that the return current (and in fact, any current) always follows the path of least impedance.

Comment: For DC and low frequency stuff (<few MHz/>few hundred ns long switching edges, not too much RF magic to worry about) the ground plane will be the return path. Once you get into the VHF range, the return path is usually the path of least impedance. If your vcc plane has lots of ceramic decoupling then the return current will flow along the closest layer (that either has good capacitive coupling to ground or *is* ground)

Comment: @Sam I dont know how the decap. capacitor has affect on return current since return path is a huge road and capacitor is at near of pin. Only thing i know about dec. cap. is that they have freq. characteristics so by connecting a few of them parallel we are getting low impedance and they provide more constant voltage level we want.

Comment: @Enric Blanco So in this case since a continuous ground will probably have the lowest impedance then it will be our return current path since a partial copper pour on any layer cannot have lower impedance than a fully poured ground layer right

Comment: @snrIcmn Yes, but how you reach each plane (vias) will have far more impact on impedance that the copper pour on the planes themselves.

Comment: *Good* ceramic decoupling capacitors present pretty close to a short circuit to high frequency signals, which is why at the higher end of the frequency scale they can allow a return current to pass between layers. The DC/LF will likely go through the ground plane but the multi-MHz stuff will want to stay as close to the signal trace as possible, if there are decoupling caps close by that allow the HF to get closer to the signal trace by running along the VCC layer, then it'll do it. If nothing's running at over a few MHz and nothing's producing sub-100ns switching edges, then I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @Enric Blanco Thanks. But there is no physically reaching. I mean if we wire a trace from source to receiver like from mcu pin to i2c sensor pin than the electromagnetic field will do the trick and the current will follow same path in return but on plane. So actually it seems to me like  we arent making physical connection to anywhere. I am confused :)

Comment: @Sam thanks. So to sum up actually all these details on impedance ground plane layer stacking etc. are important when things at high speed or rf high freq. I dont need to worry too much in a low freq. circuit of mcu sensors etc.

Comment: The current will split all possible ways according to their impedance, so the shortest and more conductive way would get more current, than longer and less conductive. But you can think about each wire/via/connector/etc as of combination of resistor and (usually reaaly small) capacitance and inductance. Then you have to solve the resulting net to get current and voltage value everywhere. Usually this does not matter much, as there is one wide path and nearly all current go that way and there is such small resistence on the path, that the voltage is nearly zero for practical resons anyway.

Comment: Why do you care about return current? Are you concerned about radiated emissions or signal integrity? Or something else? In any case, you should always route your fastest edge signals immediately adjacent to a continuous plane. If the plane has any breaks in it, don't route the fast-edge signals over the breaks. This applies to both choices of stackup. Clocks and any signals with fast rise and fall times should be immediately adjacent to GND. If you put GND on an internal layer, you can have two trace layers next to GND. Something to consider.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you. I am trying to learn as much as possible. Can i ask one more thing, I understand if gnd in internal there is 2 layer adjacent but if we have 4 layer and can 3 of them be used for high speed tracing where 4th one will be full gorund plane. Stack up is like signal ground signal signal

Comment: Check out this article on Return Current Routing: https://embeetle.com/#blog/return-currents